# PING_PONG between dotnetcore 2.2 MVC app and ADFS: authentication failed + redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

When I start my application locally, it is working as expected (except the redirection to the signin-wsfed: https://localhost:5001/signin-wsfed page... but I do not believe it could be linked)

After the deployment, I deploy using docker-compose, the first connection redirect to ADFS authentication page, but after login, I'm redirected to an error page (there are 6 calls: back to my application, back to ADFS, application, ADFS...)

Here are my logs:

```
[root@myserver docker]# docker-compose up -d
Recreating engstats ...
Recreating engstats ... done
[root@myserver docker]# docker-compose logs --tail=50 -f engstats
Attaching to engstats
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
engstats       |       User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
engstats       |       Creating key {eafb1561-dc94-4ab7-892d-f15b6ee3b122} with creation date 2019-07-22 14:23:04Z, activation date 2019-07-22 14:23:04Z, and expiration date 2019-10-20 14:23:04Z.
engstats       | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
engstats       |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {eafb1561-dc94-4ab7-892d-f15b6ee3b122} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[39]
engstats       |       Writing data to file '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys/key-eafb1561-dc94-4ab7-892d-f15b6ee3b122.xml'.
engstats       | Hosting environment: Production
engstats       | Content root path: /app
engstats       | Now listening on: http://[::]:80
engstats       | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://engstats.xxx.com/
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 499.6897ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 642.5432ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://engstats.xxx.com/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7477
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[5]
engstats       |       CORS policy execution failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[6]
engstats       |       Request origin https://fs.xxx.com does not have permission to access the resource.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 1.1351ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 5.1655ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
engstats       |       Connection id "0HLOEM0HV2CPL", Request id "0HLOEM0HV2CPL:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://engstats.xxx.com/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7483
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[5]
engstats       |       CORS policy execution failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[6]
engstats       |       Request origin https://fs.xxx.com does not have permission to access the resource.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 0.5585ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 1.1309ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
engstats       |       Connection id "0HLOEM0HV2CPM", Request id "0HLOEM0HV2CPM:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://engstats.xxx.com/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7483
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[5]
engstats       |       CORS policy execution failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[6]
engstats       |       Request origin https://fs.xxx.com does not have permission to access the resource.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 0.3882ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 0.8346ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
engstats       |       Connection id "0HLOEM0HV2CPN", Request id "0HLOEM0HV2CPN:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://engstats.xxx.com/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7487
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[5]
engstats       |       CORS policy execution failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[6]
engstats       |       Request origin https://fs.xxx.com does not have permission to access the resource.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 0.4174ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 0.8768ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
engstats       |       Connection id "0HLOEM0HV2CPO", Request id "0HLOEM0HV2CPO:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://engstats.xxx.com/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7485
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[5]
engstats       |       CORS policy execution failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[6]
engstats       |       Request origin https://fs.xxx.com does not have permission to access the resource.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 0.6451ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 1.239ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
engstats       |       Connection id "0HLOEM0HV2CPP", Request id "0HLOEM0HV2CPP:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://engstats.xxx.com/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7503
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[5]
engstats       |       CORS policy execution failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[6]
engstats       |       Request origin https://fs.xxx.com does not have permission to access the resource.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 0.4313ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 0.8877ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
engstats       |       Connection id "0HLOEM0HV2CPQ", Request id "0HLOEM0HV2CPQ:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

Here is the content of my Startup.cs class:

```
public class Startup : IStartup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Startup"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="configuration">The current configuration.</param>
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.Configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current configuration.
        /// </summary>
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the available services for this application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services">The list of services to update.</param>
        /// <returns>The initialized service provider for the application.</returns>
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string baseUrl = this.Configuration["RootUrl"] ?? "https://localhost:5001";

            if (services is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
            }

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "default",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(baseUrl);
                    });
            });

            services.AddOptions();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddWsFederation(options =>
            {
                // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
                options.MetadataAddress = "https://fs.xxx.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";

                // Wtrealm is the app's identifier in the Active Directory instance.
                // For ADFS, use the relying party's identifier, its WS-Federation Passive protocol URL:
                options.Wtrealm = baseUrl;
            })
            .AddCookie();
            services.AddHttpsRedirection(options => options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently);
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddSingleton<TeamsService>();

            services.AddSonarqubeClient(this.Configuration);
            services.AddJiraClient(this.Configuration);

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure the HTTP request pipeline and the available services.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">The current application builder.</param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (app is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
            }

            IHostingEnvironment env = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();

            app.UseExceptionMiddleware();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("default");

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

I added fs as accepted core policy (builder.WithOrigins), and now the logs are:

```
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
engstats       |       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://engstats.xxx.com/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded 7481
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
engstats       |       CORS policy execution successful.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
engstats       |       Executing endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Route matched with {action = "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController (xxx.Dashboard).
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
engstats       |       Authorization failed.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
engstats       |       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
engstats       |       Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler[12]
engstats       |       AuthenticationScheme: WsFederation was challenged.
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
engstats       |       Executed action xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard) in 0.406ms
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
engstats       |       Executed endpoint 'xxx.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController.Index (xxx.Dashboard)'
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
engstats       |       Request finished in 0.8534ms 302
engstats       | info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
engstats       |       Connection id "0HLOEMR97B67V", Request id "0HLOEMR97B67V:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

I want to be able to connect to my application using ADFS authentication...
Thank you to help me.
Regards,
Nicolas

Comment: There is an Authorization tag on Home controller... But based on the logged error message: Authorization failed.and Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
I believe it could be due to the way how DotNetCore 2.2 manage the filter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In ADFS, the **Relying party identifiers** must be https://engstats.xxx.com//signin-wsfed

Adding **/signin-wsfed** in my ADFS configuration solved the issue